# Dplyr non-standard evaluation mixing a column name with a variable value

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to come to grips with non-standard evaluation using dplyr.  I think my problem is simple enough....I simply want to divide a data.frame's column by a specific amount but I wish to encapsulate this functionality in a function.  I can achieve this functionality using base R but (for the sake of code consistency) I want to use dplyr mutate_ function.

Here is an example using base R.

```
fn_example <- function(df, divisor) {
df$x <- df$x / divisor
# want to replace the above with "dplyr:mutate_"  ????
return(df)
}

df_test <- data.frame (x = c(100, 200, 300, 400), y = c(393, 291, 45, 32))
fn_example(df_test, 2)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: df <- mutate(df, x = x / divisor)?

Comment: oh. That simple.  Thanks. Was messing around with non-standard evaluation.  Thank you!

Comment: @markthekoala, you would need standard evaluation (`mutate_`) for example if you wanted to include the column to be mutated as a function argument for flexibility